# How to check if an item in a list appears in csv?

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a list of items:

```
List = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
```

and a csv file:

```
apple
kiwi
banana
orange
pear
```

I am trying to see for each item in the list if it matches the first column of the csv, and if it does, append a '1' to the end of the row (otherwise appending a '0'), but I am a bit lost. The code below is pretty much what I'm trying to get the end result to be.

```
apple, 1
kiwi, 0
banana, 1
orange, 1
pear, 0
```

I am *very* new to python and would really appreciate any help! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried below code, which will store result in CSV

```
import csv

lists = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
nf = csv.writer(open("output.csv", "w"))
with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if(''.join(row) in lists):
            nf.writerow([''.join(row),1])
        else:
            nf.writerow([''.join(row),0])
```

**OUTPUT in CSV**

```
apple,1
kiwi,0
banana,1
orange,1
pear,0
```

Comment: @hsifyllej Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your csv file is rather a plain text file. But also a valid csv, so I'll treat it like one.

Read line by line and print 0 or 1 alongside the data using a ternary expression. Quick & easy, no dictionary or counters needed and preserves the order:

```
import csv

List = {'apple', 'banana', 'orange'}

with open("csv.csv") as f:
    cr = csv.reader(f)
    for row in cr:
        print("{}, {}".format(row[0],1 if row[0] in List else 0))
```

since it's not really a csv, basic line by line read will do too:

```
List = {'apple', 'banana', 'orange'}

with open("csv.csv") as f:
    for item in f:
        item = item.strip()
        print("{}, {}".format(item,1 if item in List else 0))
```

note that in both examples I have used a `set`, not a `list`. Makes a difference speed-wise when there are a lot of items.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this. It'll read from the csv, count how many times each fruit is found in your list, then overwrite the csv file with the new data.

```
import csv

List = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
data = []
filename = 'file.csv'

with open(filename, newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)

for item in List:
    for fruit in data:
        if item in fruit:
            fruit[1] = int(fruit[1]) + 1

with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using the `csv` module in the Python standard library, specifically [the csv.reader() method.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader)

```
import csv

fruit_list = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange']
fruit_in_file = {}

with open('csv_file.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    fruit_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in fruit_reader:
        fruit = row[0]
        if fruit in fruit_list:
            fruit_in_file[fruit] = 1
        else:
            fruit_in_file[fruit] = 0

print(fruit_in_file)
>>> {'apple': 1, 'kiwi': 0, 'orange': 1, 'banana': 1, 'pear': 0}
```

After achieving this, it seems from your question that you want to write a csv file containing this data, so we'll iterate through our `dict` and write to a csv file using the [csv.writer() method.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer):

```
with open('new_csv_file.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fruit_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for key, value in fruit_in_file.items():
        fruit_writer.writerow([key, value])
```